# Encrypted database on device or cloud stored database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore, sqlcipher

I have a pre-populated SQLite database for my Android app and I need to do some reads to show elements for an autoCompleteTextView and then other few operation, only reads on the database.

In the past days I've read about SQLCipher and Cloud Firestore by Firebase. SQLCipher seems what I was looking for but I read that I can't use it with a pre-populated database. I think that Firestore (or any other cloud service) it's my only other solution but I'm a little worried about the price and the possibile delay between the input on the ACTV and the server results.

The database does not contain any user information or other sensitive data, I just want to protect my work. I've no need for the strongest protection.

Can I use Firestore with my SQLite database? Are there any other solution for my problem? Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to protect and why?

Comment: I want to protect my data inside the db. I know that without protection anyone can have access to it so at first I thought about encrypt it but then I read that I cannot use SQLCipher with a pre-populated database. So I think that I have to use a cloud solution, but I don't know if it's needed and if Firestore it's the best in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Firebase, you need to know that there is way in which you can secure your database very simply using [Firebase Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/).

> Firebase Realtime Database Rules determine who has read and write access to your database, how your data is structured, and what indexes exist. These rules live on the Firebase servers and are enforced automatically at all times. Every read and write request will only be completed if your rules allow it. By default, your rules are set to allow only authenticated users full read and write access to your database. This is to protect your database from abuse until you have time to customize your rules or set up authentication.

If you want to use the new Firestore release (which is currently in beta release) please take a look at [Secure Data in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) offical documentation for more informations.

Another thing to note is that also [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) can provide `offline capabilities`. So the pplications will work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. So there is no need for other database in order to achieve that.

Another thing to note is that Firebase can provide [Anonymously Authenticatin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

As a conclusion Firebase can provide you security, even your app does or does not contain any user information or other sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try Firestore in the next days. Is there any problem on using the beta release?

Comment: Is there a way to add my pre-populated db or a fast way to add my data to Firestore?

Comment: As far as i tested, i didn't have any problem but as you probably know, feature availability and support for product integrations and platforms will continue to improve as the product matures. Note, that there is no magic button that can allow you to convert your actual database to Firebase, you need to do it yourself. Remember, Firebase is a NoSQL database, which is structured as pair of key and values. One you achieve addig the data to Firebase, i'm sure you'll find other very useful features.

Comment: You can wait also for other answers, but if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!